# Please help me in socket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets

Problem while making connection with server.

server side:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
ip = "let ip address of server, cant type real one for security purposes, example: 1.2.3.4"
port = 9999
def make_socket(ip, port):
    global server
    try:
        server = socket.socket()
        server.bind((ip, port))
    except:
        make_socket(ip, port)
def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"Connected with {addr}\n")
    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if msg == "exit()":
            connected = False
        if len(msg) > 0:
            print(f"CLIENT: {msg}")
            if connected:
                msg = input("You: ")
                if len(msg) > 0:
                    conn.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
    conn.close()
def make_connection():
    server.listen(2)
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"ACTIVE CONNECTIONS:{threading.activeCount() - 1}")
print("SERVER INITIATED.")
make_socket(ip, port)
make_connection()
```

client side:

```
import socket
ip = "same address as written in server side, example: 1.2.3.4"
port = 9999
client = socket.socket()
client.connect((ip, port))
def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode("utf-8")
    client.send(message)
run = True
while run:
    msg = input("You: ")
    if msg == "exit()":
        send(msg)
        run = False
    else:
        send(msg)
    print(f"Server: {client.recv(100).decode('utf-8')}")
```

It runs as expected in the same pc.

But when I am running client script and server script in 2 different pcs, they are not connecting. Even though the address is same. I have to type the ip address of server in `server.bind` and `client.connect`, right? They both should be same, right?

Answer (score 1):

The IP address you pass to `client.connect()` should be the IP address of the computer where the server is running (if it's the same computer as where the client is running, you can just pass `127.0.0.1` as that address always means localhost).  For the `bind()` call I recommend passing in `''` (i.e. an empty string) as the address, so that your server will accept incoming connections from any active network interface.  You only need to pass in an explicit IP address to `bind()` if you want limit incoming connections to only those coming through the local network card that is associated with the specified IP address.

Comment: I have passed the same address as that of server in bind and connect function.