# login bot with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Hello the process of login to my bank account is very tedious because it has a randomly generated keyboard that changes letters positions all the time can I make a bot to do it in my place?? I tried it with selenium but because the letters positions change all the time on the keyboard I could not locate the letters with the xpath and the buttons don't have an id.

Comment: Sadly this is not an answer for your question, but can you help me in this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69180637/13845045

Comment: Can we have page url ? if not please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: this is the page url:https://ebanking.cpa-bank.dz/customer/                                                       just enter a random username number then it gets you to the tricky part in the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to find the buttons by text using this:

```py
def find_button_by_text(text):
  for i in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button'):
    if i.text == text:
      return i
```

then click it